# Cast posted form to a class in ASP.Net VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms

Is there any way to Cast a posted form to a class?

I have 3 TextBox(es) with id: FirstName, LastName, Age

My class definition:

```
Public Class Person
  Public Property FirstName As String
  Public Property LastName As String
  Public Property Age As String
End Class
```

I can "triple-translate" but that seems so inefficient:

```
tDict = Dictionary(Of String, String)
tDict.Add (each NameValue pair in Request.Form using For Each)
Json = JavaScriptSerializer()
jText = Json.Serialize(tDict)
MyObj As Person = Json.Deserialize(Of Person)(jText)
```

I wasted hours searching for a solution, I just can't find anything.

Note: I am NOT using "webforms" (), this is just a simple form POST.
Thanks!

Comment: You said you're not using Web Forms, but you didn't say what you *are* using. For example, MVC and Web API have a model binder that can do what you want.

Comment: @mason - All I'm using is "File > New Website", ASP.Net V4.0, VWD2010 (sorry I'm not versed on the terms for all the flavors).  I think the technical answer is "Web Forms", but I am NOT using the <form runat="server"> tag

Comment: Add your entire Web code. What's the filename and path?

Comment: @mason - a sincere thanks for attempting to help, sorry but I can't think of any reason why the filename and path are pertinent. This is for a PHI (protected health information) site, so I must sanitize and hand-craft any samples for here.  Basically, I have created a function that lets me: `PersonData = FormToClass(Of Person)(Request)`  This works quite slick!  I just create the class property names according to the form field names, and voila! All the form data is now in a class with a single line of code.  It's too bad my function has to do a 3-step conversion, doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: It's pertinent because we have to know the context of the code. You're not saying how the code is reached. It's probably Web Forms, but you're saying it's not. There should be no reason that you can't reveal a filename or where it's located within your project. When you added the file to your site, what file type did you choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be:  there is no way to cast a POSTED form to a class.